# How to find last() element in webdriverIO with find by elements $$

Tags: webdriver-io

Below is example fo Protractor which has last() function to filter

admin.elements.executions.**last**().element(by.css('[value="REQUIRED"]'))

How to do in webdriverIO

need to find last element in $$

Answer (score 0):

You can use :last-child [details here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-child.phplin) or you can follow this link https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/$$